# Alterar background color div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando alterar a cor de fundo da `div` com as classes `wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left` , mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguem teria alguma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: já tentou colocar o "important" na frente, exemplo: background-color: red !important;

Comment: Coloque o código para uma análise melhor :)

Comment: Renan edite a sua pergunta e coloque o que vc tem de código HTML e CSS se usou algo além do original do Bootstrap. Só perguntando assim não tem como te ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns casos que mesmo utilizando o !important, a nova aplicação não funciona. São casos como:

Outra classe utilizando !important:

Neste caso é só verificar a disposição das classes, por exemplo, `wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left`, a ultima aplicação de estilo será da ultima classe, então se você tiver:

-- bootstrap.css

```
.wrapper{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.row-offcanvas-left{
    color: #000000; //está cor será aplicada
}
```

Mas caso a classe `wrapper` tenha o `!important` ela será aplicada. E se as duas  classes tiverem o `!important` a `row-offcanvas-left` será aplicada. Mas supondo que sua classe `row-offcanvas-left` está utilizando o important mas não está funcionando.

Aplicação da chamada de arquivo:

Caso você tenha um arquivo style.css e outro bootstrap.css, quando este arquivo é chamado também é alterado o resultado. Por exemplo, se você tiver a classe `row-offcanvas-left` nos dois arquivos, o arquivo que for chamado por ultimo, será o estilo aplicado:

--- index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> //arquivo que sera aplicado o estilo
```

--- index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">//arquivo que sera aplicado o estilo
```

Isto se da devido a forma que os arquivos .html e .css são interpretados pelo navegador. Como se estivesse lendo um livro, da esquerda para direita, de cima para baixo.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione uma nova classe em sua div por exemplo `<div class="background">`
E no código CSS faça assim.

```
<style>
  .background{ background-color: blue; }
  // Caso não funcione adicione o !important no final do css
</style>
```